# Can i use a generic implicit or explicit operator? C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

How do i change the following statement so it accepts any type instead of long? Now here is the catch, if there is no constructor i dont want it compiling. So if theres a constructor for string, long and double but no bool how do i have this one line work for all of these support types?

ATM i just copied pasted it but i wouldnt like doing that if i had 20types (as trivial as the task may be)

```
public static explicit operator MyClass(long v) { return new MyClass(v); }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now I can tell you that the answer to you question is "No, we can't" because:

> User-defined conversion must convert to or from the enclosing type.

That's why we can't use generic types here.

```
public class Order
{
    public string Vender { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherOrder
{
    public string Vender { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public static explicit operator AnotherOrder(Order o)
    {
        //this method can be put in Order or AnotherOrder only
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it works:

```
public static explicit operator MyClass<T>(T t) where T:new()
{ 
  return new MyClass(t);
}
```

**EDIT**

I checked your request just now and found sth weird.
**"So if theres a constructor for string, long and double but no bool"**
Can you tell me why you want to do this.

**EDIT**

I tried on my machine, it seems that generic types can't be used in explicit methods. Maybe we can only go back to an object parameter?

Comment: nope. it thinks MyClass is a generic<T>. error --> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Bonus: The non-generic type 'MyClass' cannot be used with type arguments

Comment: What do you mean it thinks MyClass is a generic<T>? AFAIK this is the correct implementation of your request.

Comment: If you read the error msg i pasted above the C# compiler think that the return type is MyClass<T> as in `class MyClass<T> { ...`

Answer (score 0):

Use Object type, if I'm not mistaken.

```
public static explicit operator MyClass(object v) { return new MyClass(v); }
```

Comment: may be the constructor thing is the constraint you need. Can you please more details in your kind as to how you want to use it in client-code.. ?

Comment: I think its not possible. But the problem is object is a type so the compiler will look for a MyClass(object) constructor.